# String value time zone sorting

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I want to  sort the string value that containing time zone value  to do that i am  implements the Comparable interface.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TimeZoneModel implements Comparable {
    private Integer id;
    private String value;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        value = value;
    }

    public TimeZoneModel(String value){
        this.value= value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object object) {
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel= null;

        if(object instanceof TimeZoneModel){
            timezoneModel=(TimeZoneModel)object;
        }

        return /*value.compareTo*/((timezoneModel.getValue()!=null?timezoneModel.getValue():"")).compareTo(value);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel = new TimeZoneModel("+01:00");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel1 = new TimeZoneModel("+02:30");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel2 = new TimeZoneModel("-01:00");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel3 = new TimeZoneModel("-11:00");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel4 = new TimeZoneModel("+05:00");

         List<TimeZoneModel> timeZoneModelList = new ArrayList<TimeZoneModel>();
         timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel);
         timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel1);
         timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel2);
         timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel3);
         timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel4);

         Collections.sort(timeZoneModelList);

         for(TimeZoneModel timezoneModelw : timeZoneModelList){
             System.out.println(timezoneModelw.getValue());
         }
     }
 }
```

In the above program, I want to  make a custom sorting on the bases of value. I used comparable interface for that.

The output i am getting:

```
-11:00
-01:00
+05:00
+02:30
+01:00
```

The expected output is:

```
-11:00
-01:00
+01:00
+02:30
+05:00
```

I want to skip the String to integer conversion. integer conversation is last option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below version of `compareTo` method

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Object object) {

    TimeZoneModel timezoneModel = null;

    Double val1 = 0d;
    Double val2 = 0d;

    if (object instanceof TimeZoneModel) {
        timezoneModel = (TimeZoneModel) object;

        String strVal = timezoneModel.getValue();

        if (strVal != null) {

            strVal = strVal.replace(":", ".");

            if (strVal.contains("-")) {

                val1 = Double.valueOf(strVal.replace("-", ""));
                val1 = val1 * -1;

            } else {
                val1 = Double.valueOf(strVal.replace("+", ""));
            }

        }

        String value = this.value.replace(":", ".");

        if (value.contains("-")) {

            val2 = Double.valueOf(value.replace("-", ""));
            val2 = val2 * -1;

        } else {
            val2 = Double.valueOf(value.replace("+", ""));
        }

    }

    return val2.compareTo(val1);
}
```

What I did is for comparing I converted the String value to `Double` without loosing the `sign` and the `minutes` value. I have used the `String.replace` method for the same. (ie. for removing the `+ - :`)

Answer (score 1):

Your current sort is based on String value, on a descending way. In standard charset (as Ascii or UTF-8), the `+` sign is before `-`, and that's why all your strings starting with `-` are before those starting with `+`, and that's why for a given sign, the strings are descending.

You should add more logic in your `compareTo` method. There are several ways to do it. You can firstly compare the first char to sort the strings in function of their signs. If the signs are different, you already know the order, and if the signs are equals then :

- if the sign is `-` then  keep your code;
- if the sign is `+` invert your code.

Answer (score 0):

for `timeZoneModelList` you can use `Arrays.sort()` instead `Collections.sort()` but maybe it change the output like this:

```
+01:00
+02:30
+05:00
-01:00
-11:00
```

Answer (score 0):

As Val Bonn noticed, there are different cases, based on the sign. If numbers are negative, then the "bigger number" is less, whereas if the numbers as positive, the "smaller number is less".

If the signs are different, negative is always smaller than positive.

So your code becomes something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class TimeZoneModel implements Comparable {
    private Integer id;
    private String value;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        value = value;
    }

    public  TimeZoneModel(String value){
        this.value= value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object object) {
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel= null;
        if(object instanceof TimeZoneModel){
            timezoneModel=(TimeZoneModel)object;
        }
        // need to handle timezoneModel being null
        if (timezoneModel.getValue() != null) {
            char sign = timezoneModel.getValue().charAt(0);
            if (sign == '+') {
                if (value.charAt(0) == '+')
                    return value.compareTo(timezoneModel.getValue());
                else
                    return -1;
            }
            else if (sign == '-')
                if (value.charAt(0) == '-')
                    return  - value.compareTo(timezoneModel.getValue());
                else
                    return 1;
        }
        return "".compareTo(value);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel = new TimeZoneModel("+01:00");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel1 = new TimeZoneModel("+02:30");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel2 = new TimeZoneModel("-01:00");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel3 = new TimeZoneModel("-11:00");
        TimeZoneModel timezoneModel4 = new TimeZoneModel("+05:00");

        List<TimeZoneModel> timeZoneModelList = new ArrayList<TimeZoneModel>();
        timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel);
        timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel1);
        timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel2);
        timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel3);
        timeZoneModelList.add(timezoneModel4);

        Collections.sort(timeZoneModelList);
        for(TimeZoneModel timezoneModelw : timeZoneModelList){
            System.out.println(timezoneModelw.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

You may have stated that you don't want to convert to Integers, but this approach is wrong, and the code needed to make this work, as you can see, is very complicated.